# Start Activity on mobile restart

Tags: android, restart

I Want to design an App. Which will start on mobile restart. 
I am able to start my activity by using "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" intent
but "SAMSUNG NOTE"  has facility to restart mobile not needed to switch off and then on
here i am facing problem  my app is not starting on "restart"

Comment: No,it is not going to be happen because this action is system reserved,You may Check this Developer link....http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_REBOOT,

Comment: "I Want to design an App. Which will start on mobile restart." -- then write your own home screen, please.

Comment: Do you really want to start an app on restart, or do you want a background process (ie an Android Service) to start when the phones starts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem Solved for now by removing code which is commented.

```
    Intent startMainActivity = new Intent(context,MyActivity.class);      
    startMainActivity.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(startMainActivity);
   /* Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(startMain);*/
```

I was using commented code to launch home screen after my  app is launched